# PowerPoint VBA: Chart.PlotArea.InsideHeight assignment looses decimal digits

Tags: vba, double, powerpoint

I'm trying to write a makro in VBA for PP2016 that will adjust the size of the PlotArea of a Chart. What I tried is:

```
Sub setPlotArea()
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea
    .InsideHeight = 110.253
    MsgBox (.InsideHeight)
End With
End Sub
```

The MsgBox returns **110**. The decimal digits are lost. 
Why can't I assign a Double value to .InsideHeight? The Object Catalog states, that InsideHeight should be a Double. (Same Problem occurs with .Chart.Legend.Height)

I'm grateful for every hint, until now I didn't even find a workaround for this.

**Edit 1:** 
If I Change the Code to

```
Sub setPlotArea()
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(1).Chart.PlotArea
    MsgBox (.InsideHeight)
    .InsideHeight = 110.253
    MsgBox (.InsideHeight)
End With
End Sub
```

And I run the macro on a newly created Chart (...Insert -> Bar Chart) then the first MsgBox returns 220.794251968504, the second one however still returns 110. So obviously .InsideHeight can have a decimal number (double) as value. I just cannot assign it.

Comment: Use `Msgbox Format(.InsdeHeight,"##0.###")

Comment: It may be a Double but it's in Points and you will only get a whole number of those.

Comment: @nishit dey: MsgBox Format(.InsideHeight,"##0.###") returns "110." So it is not just a matter of the formating of the string.

Comment: @Rory: I edited the original Question. Obviously .InsideHeight can have (and had) decimal numbers as a value. Just I cannot assign a decimal value to it. You are right, it is in points, but why should points not be divisable?

Comment: `MsgBox Format(.InsideHeight,"000.000") ` try this. You can use the `custom format` of the excel in this to match your desired output. Thanks

Comment: They should be, but the plotarea won't accept a non-integer value as far as I know. You can set the height of the chartobject, or even the chartarea to a value like 12.75 but it won't work with the plot area.

Comment: @nishit dey: MsgBox Format(.InsideHeight,"000.000") returns 110.000 in the MsgBox.